# I want to select all href through xpath in selenium java webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am selecting all `href` through `xpath` in `selenium java`. How do I get the correct `href` for selecting all?

Exception in thread "main" `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[[starts-with(@href,'javascript:doViewDispute')]`

Because of the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 
//a[[starts-with(@href,'javascript:doViewDispute')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

```
List<WebElement> oLinksOnPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[[starts-with(@href,'javascript:doViewDispute')]"));
                    System.out.print ( oLinksOnPage );

                    System.out.println(oLinksOnPage.size());

                    for(i = 0; i<oLinksOnPage.size(); i++){

                        System.out.println(oLinksOnPage.get(i).getText());

                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors in your initial code: `List oLinksOnPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[[starts-with(@href,'javascript:doViewDispute')]"));`

First, you can't have just `List`; you have to explain what the list is, so `List<WebElement>`.

Second, you have two opening brackets, but only one closing in your xpath string.

So your final code should be:

```
List<WebElement> oLinksOnPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'javascript:doViewDispute')]"));
```

Try that and see if it works better for you.

Comment: This should nail the OP.

Comment: Not sure why people are editing my answer into the original post.

Comment: I don't see your answer edited. Can you please elaborate what exactly you meant...

Comment: I mean, the original post is being edited to make my answer seem redundant. As in fixing the mistakes pointed out. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you feel _the original post was being edited to make your answer seem redundant_ feel free to raise a Custom Flag _in need of moderator intervention_ and explain the situation so someone from the moderator team may look into the issue and help us out.